# Альтернатива TinyMce на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли сейчас альтернатива этому плагину? Т.е. расширенный редактор.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пользоваться расширенными функциями TinyMCE, установите плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-edit/ и настраивайте редактор как угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Да их полно, а из вопроса не совсем ясно, что именно требуется от альтернативы. Вот несколько примеров:

[CKEditor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/)

[Tiny MCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)

Ну и, в конце концов, [Visual Composer](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431)